# Image collection monthly averages using geemap package

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I am trying to convert some code snippets from GEE JavaScript to Python. This code computes the monthly averages of NDVI images given a range of years and a range of months.

This is my code in JavaScript:

```
var years = ee.List.sequence(2013, 2021);
var sowingMonths = ee.List.sequence(10, 12);
var growingMonths = ee.List.sequence(1, 4);

monthly_Sowing_Avg = function (Collection){
 return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
   years.map(function(year) {
     return sowingMonths.map(function(month) {
       return Collection
       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))
       .mean()
       .set({'month': month, 'year': year});
 });
}).flatten())}
```

and this is what I tried to do in Python:

```
years = ee.List.sequence(2013, 2021)
sowingMonths = ee.List.sequence(10, 12)
growingMonths = ee.List.sequence(1, 4)
def monthly_Sowing_Avg (collection, years, months):

 def mapOverMonths (month):
   return  sowCol.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year')) \
                 .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month')) \
                 .mean() \
                 .set({'month': month, 'year': year})

 def mapOverYears (year):
   return Months.map(mapOverMonths)

 return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(years.map(mapOverYears))
```

Is the Python version correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this (not very optimized solution):

```
def monthly_Avg (collection, years, months):
  avg = []
  for year in years:
    for month in months:
      Monthly_avg = collection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year')) \
                              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month')) \
                              .mean() \
                              .set({'month': month, 'year': year})
      avg.append (Monthly_avg)
  return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(avg)

## Compute monthly averages for both seasons
monthly_sowing_Avg = monthly_Avg (ndvi_sowSeason, years, sowingMonths)
monthly_growing_Avg = monthly_Avg (ndvi_growSeason, years, growingMonths)
```

`years`,  `sowingMonths`, and  `growingMonths` are lists.